# ASP._Page_default_cshtml.Execute()': no suitable method found to override

Tags: razor, webmatrix

While trying **Microsoft WebMatrix Calendar Template**, it works locally without any trouble but when I try the same in host server, it does not work and giving the following error:

**Compiler Error Message:** CS0115: 'ASP._Page_default_cshtml.Execute()': no suitable method found to override

```
Line 41:         }
Line 42:         
Line 43:         public override void Execute() {
Line 44: 
Line 45:
```

The complete compilation source is:

```
Line 1:    #pragma checksum "E:\web\nazmulwebco\htdocs\ical\default.cshtml" "{406ea660-64cf-4c82-b6f0-42d48172a799}" "91704A43AA481FE0EBCE348C223AE605"
Line 2:    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Line 3:    // <auto-generated>
Line 4:    //     This code was generated by a tool.
Line 5:    //     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.239
Line 6:    //
Line 7:    //     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
Line 8:    //     the code is regenerated.
Line 9:    // </auto-generated>
Line 10:   //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Line 11:   
Line 12:   namespace ASP {
Line 13:       using System;
Line 14:       using System.Collections.Generic;
Line 15:       using System.IO;
Line 16:       using System.Linq;
Line 17:       using System.Net;
Line 18:       using System.Web;
Line 19:       using System.Web.Helpers;
Line 20:       using System.Web.Security;
Line 21:       using System.Web.UI;
Line 22:       using System.Web.WebPages;
Line 23:       using System.Web.WebPages.Html;
Line 24:       using WebMatrix.Data;
Line 25:       using WebMatrix.WebData;
Line 26:       using Microsoft.Web.Helpers;
Line 27:       
Line 28:       
Line 29:       public class _Page_default_cshtml {
Line 30:           
Line 31:   #line hidden
Line 32:   
Line 33:           
Line 34:           public _Page_default_cshtml() {
Line 35:           }
Line 36:           
Line 37:           protected System.Web.HttpApplication ApplicationInstance {
Line 38:               get {
Line 39:                   return ((System.Web.HttpApplication)(Context.ApplicationInstance));
Line 40:               }
Line 41:           }
Line 42:           
Line 43:           public override void Execute() {
Line 44:   
Line 45:               
Line 46:               #line 1 "E:\web\nazmulwebco\htdocs\ical\default.cshtml"
Line 47:     
Line 48:       // Redirect to the initial main page
Line 49:       Response.Redirect("~/Calendar");
Line 50:   
Line 51:               
Line 52:               #line default
Line 53:               #line hidden
Line 54:   
Line 55:           }
Line 56:       }
Line 57:   }
Line 58:
```

Answer (score -1):

That shouldn't happen. Did you deploy via WebMatrix? It will verify you have all the right features configured on your web server as well as make sure all the right files get deployed.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I deployed via Webmatrix.

Comment: Well, if it works locally, but not when you publish, then something is probably configured wrong on the server you deployed to. Is it a shared host or your own server or ???

Comment: I would just confirm with them that they have .NET 4 installed and that they app pool running your site is set to use .NET 4 integrated.